# Swift4,IOS 12 self.performSegue not working

Tags: swift, segue, ios12

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let str = self.appDefaults.string(forKey: Constants.init().userBirthDayStrKey)
    print(str!)
    if nil != self.appDefaults.string(forKey: Constants.init().userBirthDayStrKey) {
        print("performSegue")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTimeViewScreen", sender: self)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I want to open another ViewController in the viewDidLoad method,but it not working,
what`s wrong with the code?How can I open another ViewController without click one button?

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's think about your code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
```

So you cannot perform a segue from `viewDidLoad`. Your view controller is not in the interface yet; there is nothing to segue from. You must wait until something like `viewDidAppear`.

```
    if nil != self.appDefaults.string(forKey: Constants.init().userBirthDayStrKey) {
```

So if it *is* `nil`, nothing will happen at all. How do we know if it is? You have not told us.

```
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToTimeViewScreen", sender: self)
```

So if there is no segue from this view controller with that identifier, nothing will happen. How do we know if there is?

```
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What on earth is *that* line doing there? If the segue was a presentation (modal) segue, that will cancel it and nothing will happen.

So, there are many reasons why nothing might be happening.

Comment: The code 

if nil != self.appDefaults.string(forKey: Constants.init().userBirthDayStrKey) 

is true

Comment: How my code can open the second ViewController itself?

Comment: I have  add a segue identifier,I can open the second ViewController by click a button,but now I just want to the code can do this itself when nil != self.appDefaults.string(forKey: Constants.init().userBirthDayStrKey)